# UICollectionView content frame shows correct on emulator, wrong on device

Tags: ios, ios6, ios-simulator, uicollectionview

I've been working at this one issue for a week now and I'm lost.  I have a programmatically created UICollectionViewController with custom layout.  It's a subview of my root UIViewController.  In the emulator on any resolution the view shows correctly.  But on my iPhone 4s the view seems to be the right size but the content frame doesn't fill the UICollectionView frame completely.

Does anyone have any tips on how I can debug this further or give any hints as to what this issue might be?